# Extending webpack module resolution path in Nuxt.js

Tags: webpack, module, nuxt.js, resolution

Does anyone have working examples of extending **config.resolve.modules** array in Nuxt.js?
Here's the part of nuxt.config.js with changes:

```
const pathLib = require("path");

... 

build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
        config.resolve.modules.push(pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "./scss"));
    }
}
```

"./scss" directory holds style.scss file

Adding that file into the "Global CSS" array in nuxt.config.js produces an error:

> Could not compile template
>   /sandbox/node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app/template/App.js: Cannot resolve
>   "style.scss" from "/sandbox/style.scss"

Seems that generated Nuxt webpack config just ignores the changes in config.resolve.modules.

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-modules-resolving-issue-ufnju

Any suggestions?